# Stopping Tweepy bot reply loop

Tags: python-3.x, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am new to Python so what I'm doing right now might make no sense at all. I apologize for that.

Currently I'm having trouble because the bot responses to mentions already replied. I want to prevent it from answering the same mention multiple times. So I tried to make the code retrieve highest tweet ID from already answered ones, and upadate it as the value for `new_since_id`. But it doesn't seem to work. What I wrote looks like this:

```
import tweepy, time, logging, random

CONSUMER_KEY ="XXXXX"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "XXXXX"   
ACCESS_KEY = "XXXXX"    
ACCESS_SECRET = "XXXXX"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

mentions_tweets = api.mentions_timeline(tweet_mode='extended')
    for status in api.mentions_timeline():
        update_id = str(max(status.id))
        new_since_id = update_id

def roll_100d():

    for mentions_tweet in (mentions_tweets):
        if new_since_id == mentions_tweet.id and '[Dice]' in mentions_tweet.full_text():
            diceroll = str(random.randint(1,100))
            api.update_status('@' + mentions_tweet.user.screen_name + ' Your dice result is '+ diceroll + '.',
            in_reply_to_status_id = mentions_tweet.id)

while True:
    roll_100d()
    time.sleep(15)
```

Would there be any way to make it work? I'm getting a TypeError but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=mentions_timeline#API.mentions_timeline you are using the `mentions_timeline` API endpoint but you aren't specifying the parameter `since_id`.

Comment: I fixeded it to `for status in api.mentions_timeline(since_id=nnnnn):` right below `mentions_tweets = api.mentions_timeline(tweet_mode='extended')`, but it still doesn't work, perhaps I misunderstood where to specify the parameter?

Comment: You need to reorder your code. You are calling `mentions_timeline` only once. You need to call it again with the modified `since_id` parameter to get a new unique list of twitter statuses.

Comment: @TinNguyen Sorry for answering this late. Would using `return` solve the problem then?? Sorry for asking basic stuff and thank you so much for helping!